# NodeJS Ejs Variable Render HTML

Tags: node.js, ejs, locomotivejs

You can output variables using ejs like so

```
PagesController.test = function() {
  this.title = 'test'
  this.render();
}

<title><%= title %></title>
```

However I tried including html in the variable and it just displays it as text. Is it possible to make it render as html?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need this construct:

```
<%- title %>
```

That won't escape the contents of the `title` variable.